What are the 'sometimes surprising results' that Notepad++ saves us from by disabling backwards regex search?
Out of the box, searching backwards in a document doesn't work in regular expression mode. Nppp explains in a dialog box that the capability is disabled due to unintuitive behavior:

By default, backward regex searching is disabled due to potentially unexpected results.

What kind of unexpected results are we talking about here, and why do they arise?
The manual page on regular expressions gives a hint as to the nature of the problem with a test string and regex which would yield different numbers of matches in forward and backward operation.
For the adventurous, the manual page that dialog refers to with instructions for enabling backwards regex search is here.

Backwards regex search has been reported-broken and/or disabled since v7.8.7.

The best way to check info about why a feature was removed/hidden is to check the software's repository, if available. There is a pull request that provides partial reasoning:

The full story, debated before, is that regular expression searching in a backward direction from the caret position causes matches that the user does not expect.

I could find a really quick example of it not working too well with the caret. With this text:
testexample
testtestexampleexample

if you look for test.*?example in regular mode and position the cursor anywhere, it'll always find the closest correct match. E.g. if you put it here:
testexample
test|testexampleexample

it'll find neighboring testexample as expected. But if you switch to backward direction mode and place the cursor here:
testexample
testtestexample|example

it doesn't make much sense and inconsistently finds the first line instead.

Why does it work like this? No idea, no time to analyze it, but it's surely related to the fact that most regex engines (including Boost.Regex used by N++) work forwards, not backwards, and Notepad++ uses some workarounds for the backwards functionality to simulate finding matches in the opposite direction. They couldn't implement fully reliable workarounds for the cursor position, though, and decided to disable the direction change by default instead.

Likely, unexpected results might be due to the fact that regex can search for the first, or subsequent, or last character or sequence in a line or a string.
That means if you're starting at the end, working backwards, it might specify the second occurrence of a character or it might mean the second to last occurrence. It depends on implementation of regex, and might not be IOTTMCO.

Are you answering the author's question or asking your own question?
